# Having surfaceView in each fragment

Tags: android, surfaceview

Is this bad idea? multi fragment with surfaceview.

there is a activity with two fragment.

First fragment, can pick pickture from custom gallery, or take picture from custom camera. so that i need to create surfaceview.

Second fragment, can move image to crop that was selected on previous fragment.

But it doesn't work. when i add second fragment.
When i removed first fragment then it works.

[image]

When i add second fragment, they doesn't work no more.
They didn't any response on Touch.
[image]

How do i fix this?